# How to get values from Tkinter radio button groups created in for loop

Tags: python, for-loop, tkinter, radio-button, trace

I want to create automatically several groups of 4 `Radiobuttons` in different tabs of a `Notebook`, content of each tab is created in a for loop and use trace_add on them but it is not working.

Here is an example of what my code looks like:

```
test_type_vars = []
for test_name in ["idvg0", "idvgh", "idvd0", "idvdh", "acvg0", "acvgh", "acfreq0", "noise"]:
        test_type_frame= Frame(notebook, name=test_name+"_frame")
        notebook.add(test_frame, text=test_name)
        type_var = IntVar()
        type_var.set(random.randint(1,4))
        test_type_vars.append(type_var)
        dc_type_radio = Radiobutton(test_type_frame, text="DC", variable=type_var, value=1)
        dc_type_radio.pack(side=LEFT, padx=10)
        ac_type_radio = Radiobutton(test_type_frame, text="AC", variable=type_var, value=2)
        ac_type_radio.pack(side=LEFT, padx=10)
        acfreq_type_radio = Radiobutton(test_type_frame, text="ACFREQ", variable=type_var, value=3)
        acfreq_type_radio.pack(side=LEFT, padx=10)
        noise_type_radio = Radiobutton(test_type_frame, text="Noise", variable=type_var, value=4)
        noise_type_radio.pack(side=LEFT, padx=10)

for var in test_type_vars:
    print(var.get())
    var.trace_add("write", change_test_type)

def change_test_type(var, blank, mode):
    print("FLAG")
```

The problem is that the change_test_type is never called and I never see the "FLAG" when i change the radio buttons selection but I see the random numbers printing. I can't understand why it is not working, maybe I juste made a stupid mistake

Thanks

Comment: You have already used `test_type_vars` to store those *type_vars*, so you can access those variables using `test_type_vars[0]`, `test_type_vars[1]`, etc.  So what is your issue actually?

Comment: I edited the question because it was not clear

Comment: `change_test_type()` has not been defined yet when `var.trace_add(...)` is executed.

Comment: Thanks, but I have the same problem if i put change_test_type() definition before

Comment: It works fine when putting definition of `change_test_type()` before `for var in test_type_vars` loop.  Also there is typo error on the line `notebook.add(test_frame)`, it should be `notebook.add(test_type_frame)` instead.